# Json export for Phoca Download on Joomla 3

Tags: php, mysql, json, joomla

I am looking to find out how to create an  SQL view for my Phoca Download component categories and subcategories. Usually I create the view easily in phpMyAdmin and then I enable the view from the Json export plugin on the back-end.
This method is used when I am looking to load content dynamically from a Joomla website to an phone application.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post in phpMyAdmin the below SQL query (be sure you find the correct table by browsing all pages, or just search.)

```
CREATE VIEW name_of_view
AS SELECT * FROM `xxxxx_phocadownload_categories`
WHERE `id` between 1 and 20 AND published ="1"
```

Then enable/publish from JSON export plugin (paid) the custom view you have created.